# How to Hide the "Columns" if the Columns cells are empty within a certain range?

Tags: excel, vba

How to Hide the Columns if the Columns are empty within a certain range using VBA ? For eg: In below picture If the  Columns cells are empty within range "A5:J22" then Hide those columns.Here, Columns E,F,H,I & J will be hidden.Column G will not be hidden as it has data on it on "G12".

[image]

Comment: Loop over them and use `WorksheetFunction.CountA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
Public Sub HIDE()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    lastrow = Cells(1048576, i).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastrow < 5 Then
        Columns(i).Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

- `Sum` (use if you have numbers - is faster)
- `CountA` (use if you have both numbers and texts - is slower)

  ```
  Sub test()

   Dim i As Long

   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
       For i = 5 To 10
           If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(5, i), .Cells(22, i))) > 0 Then
               .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
           Else
               .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
           End If
       Next i
   End With

  End Sub
  ```